# Setting the screen resolution for camera calibration OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, camera-calibration

I'm working on a project where the video I have was recorded at one resolution but when I plug the camera into my computer to perform the calibration with OpenCV it runs at lower resolution, so when I apply the correction to the video it's not quite right.

I am using the OpenCV calibration code, and I'm hoping someone may have already done this and be able to tell me how (and hopefully where) I can adjust the code for the desired resolution for calibration.

I have also discovered that when I adjust the resolution for just opening the camera to display an image it doesn't work unless I first reduce the frame rate, but if I run the code again with the frame rate increased to what it was originally it works, has anyone else come across this? It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Do you mean that when you are getting live video from the camera you get a different resolution than when you first record the video on the camera and let OpenCV open the recorded video file?

Comment: Yes, somebody else recorded the video and it's at a different pixel resolution than when I get a live video from the camera, the recorded video is at 704x576 and live from the camera is at 640x480, both opened using OpenCV VideoCapture.  I can change the live camera to 704x576 with the VideoCapture::set stuff but it doesn't always seem to work, and so far not with the calibration code that OpenCV has, so that's where I'm looking for help.

Comment: okay I think I've got it, between lines 148 and 149 of the OpenCV camera calibration code if I add the VideoCapture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,X) and VideoCapture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,Y)  lines it changes it to what I want but then the program runs unbearable slow, without the changes it's already pretty slow, has anyone been able to speed it up?